# How can you loop through a column and change a cell value if it contains part of a string

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to loop through all cells in column "C" and change the value to Today()-4 if the cell contains "Mon" because the report runs on a Friday. I have put Today() in cell "K5" as not sure how else to incorporate it into my

```
For Each cell In Sheets("EMAIL DATA").Range("C:C")
    If cell.Value = "*Mon*" Then
    Set cell.Value = ("K5" - 4)
    End If
Next
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below, using `DateAdd` function to substract 4 days from today's date (`Date`).

**Note**: There's no need to save today's date in Cell "K5", just use the `Date` function.

```
For Each cell In Sheets("EMAIL DATA").Range("C:C")
    If cell.Value Like "*Mon*" Then
        cell.Value = DateAdd("d", Date, -4)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks Shai. Works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

to reference the Cell K5 you need to use: `Range("K5")`.  Or Excel will see the "K5" as a litteral string and throw an error.

```
For Each cell In Sheets("EMAIL DATA").Range("C:C")
    If cell.Value Like "*Mon*" Then
    Set cell.Value = (Sheets("EMAIL DATA").Range("K5") - 4)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for your response however when using the above, the cell containing "Mon 10:31" does not change. Any idea why?